# What do i wrong?

Tags: sql, sql-server

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/30c6fe/4

Here is the code:

```
    Create table employees
(
  id integer identity(1,1) primary key,
  lastname varchar (16),
  pass_num varchar (16)
 )
;

  insert into employees values ('Ivanov', '11111111');
  insert into employees values ('Ivanov', '11111111');
  insert into employees values ('Ivanov', '55555555');
  insert into employees values ('Petrov', '22222222');
  insert into employees values ('Petrov', '22222222');
  insert into employees values ('Sidorov', '11111111');

SELECT id, lastname, pass_num
FROM employees emp
GROUP BY lastname, pass_num
HAVING min(id);
```

And 
Error: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'.

Comment: Please include your code as text inside your post.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

You have error on

```
HAVING min(id);
```

It is expecting an expression

sample

```
HAVING min(id) = 1;
```

also, your GROUP BY does not include all columns that are not in aggregate function. this should include the column id as well

```
GROUP BY lastname, pass_num
```